# Significance of minimum energy of a proton

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, protons

I have been presented with the following problem.

A neutron is confined in a nucleus of size $4 × 10^{−15}$ m. Using the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, estimate its minimum kinetic energy. Comment on the significance of your
result.

So I have found a value for the energy ($3.8\times10^{-9})$ but I fail to see the significance of this, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: $3.8 \times 10^{-9}$ whats?

Comment: According to classical physics, can a particle be at rest when it is confined to a region of space defined by a potential well? What does quantum physics say about the physics of the same situation?

Answer (score 1):

In natural units, $\hbar=1=c$, it is only meaningful to measure quantities in MeVs, so
$$
\Delta x= 4f=\frac{1}{50MeV},  
$$
while the mass of the neutron is *m* ~ 940MeV.

The kinetic energy then is crudely ≥
$$
\frac{ 1}{2m ~(2\Delta x)^2}\approx 0.332 MeV,
$$
so infinitesimally smaller than *m*, deeply non-relativistic, of course. Also much smaller than the binding energy per nucleon, larger than an MeV.

I'm not sure why you have proton in your title, but I'd doubt you are being asked to intuit β-decay.